# Finding out how many words appear in all 5 files

Tags: java

I have this program that prints out as such:

```
Max number files any word is in: 5  
Total words in all files: 880  
Total words in five files: 880  
caesar.txt  
hamlet.txt  
likeit.txt  
macbeth.txt  
romeo.txt  

List of words that appear in most files: [A, I, turn, O, after, a, time,, good, faithful, gone, etc...
```

I would like to know how many words there are that are in all 5 Shakespeare files (files used for testing can be found here: http://www.dukelearntoprogram.com/course3/archives/PracticeGladLibsData.zip). I get a long list of words, which is not helpful at all for this problem.

Here's my code in which this problem occurs:

```
import edu.duke.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class WordsInFiles {
    private HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> wordInFilesMap;

    public WordsInFiles() {
        wordInFilesMap = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>>();
    }
    private void addWordsFromFile(File file) {
        //This method should add all the words from file into the map.
        //If a word is not in the map, then you must create a new ArrayList of
        // type String with this word, and have the word map to this ArrayList.
        //If a word is already in the map, then add the current filename to its
        // ArrayList, unless the filename is already in the ArrayList.
        FileResource fileResource = new FileResource(file);
        String fileName = file.getName();
        for (String word : fileResource.words()) {
            if (!wordInFilesMap.containsKey(word)) {
                ArrayList<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();
                newList.add(fileName);
                wordInFilesMap.put(word, newList);
            }
            else if (wordInFilesMap.containsKey(word) 
                        && !wordInFilesMap.get(word).contains(fileName)) {
                ArrayList<String> currentList = wordInFilesMap.get(word);
                currentList.add(fileName);
                wordInFilesMap.put(word,currentList);
            }
        }
    }
    private void buildWordFileMap() {
        wordInFilesMap.clear();
        DirectoryResource dirResource = new DirectoryResource();
        for (File file : dirResource.selectedFiles()) {
            addWordsFromFile(file);
        }
    }
    private int maxNumber() {
        //returns the maximum number of files any word appears in, considering
        // all words from a group of files.
        int highest = 0;
        for (String word : wordInFilesMap.keySet()) {
            ArrayList<String> currentFileList = wordInFilesMap.get(word);
            int currentNum = currentFileList.size();
            if (currentNum > highest) {
                highest = currentNum;
            }
        }
        return highest;
    }
    private ArrayList<String> wordsInNumFiles(int number) {
        //returns an ArrayList of words that appear in exactly number files
        ArrayList<String> wordList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String word : wordInFilesMap.keySet()) {
            ArrayList<String> currentList = wordInFilesMap.get(word);
            int currentFileCount = currentList.size();
            if (currentFileCount == number) {
                wordList.add(word);
            }
        }
        return wordList;
    }
    private void printFilesIn(String word) {
        //prints the names of the files this word appears in, one filename per line
        ArrayList<String> fileNames = wordInFilesMap.get(word);
        for (int index=0; index < fileNames.size(); index++) {
            System.out.println(fileNames.get(index));

        }
       }
    public void tester() {
        //call buildWordFileMap to select files and build HashMap of words
        buildWordFileMap();
        //determine maximum number of files any word is in, considering all words
        int fileNum = maxNumber();
        System.out.println("Max number files any word is in: "+fileNum);

        ArrayList<String> wordsInFiles = wordsInNumFiles(fileNum);
        System.out.println("Total words in all files: "+wordsInFiles.size());
        wordsInFiles = wordsInNumFiles(5);
        System.out.println("Total words in five files: "+wordsInFiles.size());
        printFilesIn("to");
        System.out.println("\n");
        printFilesIn("and");
        System.out.println("\nList of words that appear in most files: "+wordsInFiles);

        /*for (int index=0; index < wordsInFiles.size(); index++) {
            System.out.println("Files where "+wordsInFiles.get(index)+" appear:");
            printFilesIn(wordsInFiles.get(index));
        }

        for (String key : wordInFilesMap.keySet()) {
            System.out.println("\nWord: "+key+"\tAppears in files: "
                                +wordInFilesMap.get(key));
        }*/

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a stack trace or at least an error message?  As much as I like Macbeth, I don't want to go Shakespear diving at the moment.

Comment: There's no error. I'm just looking for a way to count up the number of words that are in all 5 files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
import edu.duke.*;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

class WordsInFiles {
    private HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> wordInFilesMap;

    public WordsInFiles() {
        wordInFilesMap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
    }

    private void addWordsFromFile(File file) {
        //This method should add all the words from file into the map.
        //If a word is not in the map, then you must create a new ArrayList of
        // type String with this word, and have the word map to this ArrayList.
        //If a word is already in the map, then add the current filename to its
        // ArrayList, unless the filename is already in the ArrayList.
        FileResource fileResource = new FileResource(file);
        String fileName = file.getName();
        for (String word : fileResource.words()) {
            if (!wordInFilesMap.containsKey(word)) {
                ArrayList<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();
                newList.add(fileName);
                wordInFilesMap.put(word, newList);
            } else if (wordInFilesMap.containsKey(word)
                    && !wordInFilesMap.get(word).contains(fileName)) {
                ArrayList<String> currentList = wordInFilesMap.get(word);
                currentList.add(fileName);
                wordInFilesMap.put(word, currentList);
            }
        }
    }

    private void buildWordFileMap() {
        wordInFilesMap.clear();
        DirectoryResource dirResource = new DirectoryResource();
        for (File file : dirResource.selectedFiles()) {
            addWordsFromFile(file);
        }
    }

    private int maxNumber() {
        //returns the maximum number of files any word appears in, considering
        // all words from a group of files.
        int highest = 0;
        for (String word : wordInFilesMap.keySet()) {
            ArrayList<String> currentFileList = wordInFilesMap.get(word);
            int currentNum = currentFileList.size();
            if (currentNum > highest) {
                highest = currentNum;
            }
        }
        return highest;
    }

    private ArrayList<String> wordsInNumFiles(int number) {
        //returns an ArrayList of words that appear in exactly number files
        ArrayList<String> wordList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String word : wordInFilesMap.keySet()) {
            ArrayList<String> currentList = wordInFilesMap.get(word);
            int currentFileCount = currentList.size();
            if (currentFileCount == number) {
                wordList.add(word);
            }
        }
        return wordList;
    }

    private void printFilesIn(String word) {
        //prints the names of the files this word appears in, one filename per line
        ArrayList<String> fileNames = wordInFilesMap.get(word);
        for (int index = 0; index < fileNames.size(); index++) {
            System.out.println(fileNames.get(index));

        }
    }

    private int countWords() {
        int count = 0;
        for (String word : wordInFilesMap.keySet()) {
            List<String> currentList = wordInFilesMap.get(word);
            count += currentList.size();
        }
        return count;
    }

    public void tester() {
        //call buildWordFileMap to select files and build HashMap of words
        buildWordFileMap();

        // ++ Calc count of files in all files
        int countAllWordsInAllFiles = countWords();
        System.out.println("\nCount of all words that appear in all files: " + countAllWordsInAllFiles);
        // -- Calc count of files in all files
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new WordsInFiles().tester();
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you counting all the words in all the files? I wanted to know how many words are in all 5 files.

Comment: yes, i'm counting all words in all 5 files